# Filtering on column of ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have this (simplified for discussion) data model, and I can't seem to filter on a field of the many to many table; the property below results in "Related Field got invalid lookup: person":

```
class Person(Model):
    traveler_trips = ManyToManyField('Trip', related_name='travelers')

    @property
    def mungee_trips(self):
        return Trip.objects.filter(travelers__person=self).all()
```

Again, this is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do; I realize person.traveler_trips would give me the same result as this property, I'd like to know what I need to do to explicitly filter on columns of a ManyToManyField's underlying table - another filter I'm trying to use looks like travelers__person__idx__lt=self.idx.

Here is the schema for this join table (it does have the expected person_id column):

```
         Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                   Default                    
----------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 id             | integer |           | not null | nextval('ms_traveler_trip_id_seq'::regclass)
 person_id      | integer |           | not null | 
 trip_id        | integer |           | not null |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example `mungee_trips` query seems to return just this Person's trips (and therefore is redundant),
so you can just **access the field directly** - **`self.traveler_trips`**.

---

For accessing reverse relation in `filter` django uses [related_query_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) value. Yes, if not specified it is same as `related_name`.

In this case in filter `travelers` points to `Person` model and `Person` has no field `person`. You can use **`.filter(travelers=self)`** or filter by another field on `Person`, i.e. `.filter(travelers__name="John")` if `Person` has `name` field.

---

Also, as this method returns QuerySet, you can consider defining it as a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/) instead.

Comment: I thought I might have misunderstood the naming conventions, but when I tried what you suggested (.filter(traveler=self)) I get "Cannot resolve keyword 'traveler' into field."

Comment: Oh, yes. As related_query_name is not set it is same as related_name, so should be `.filter(travelers=self)`. Fixed.